# Does the health recovery bonus for Imperials affect food consumption?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-blades

Does the health recovery bonus for Imperials affect food consumption? I could swear the amount of health I got from food consumption did not change when I switched to the Imperial race, I could be wrong, but I don't want to spend the gems to try switching back to something else, and then switching to Imperial again if I'm wrong.

version up to date as of Dec 18 2020, I know that *some* of these things have changed since the initial release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed that it does not, in fact, affect the health you get from eating "food" laying around. I'm not certain if it affects anything other than potions.